# Cat previous file and new file together and mv to temp file.

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do the following:

- Get the previous filename(if it exists) - I've done this
- Cat the two files to a temporary file i.e. "filename.002", "filename.003" >> temp file
- mv downloaded file to somewhere or maybe delete it
- mv temp to correct filename

I have done the following:

```
set -x

substring()
{
    VAR=$1
    OFFSET=$2
    LENGTH=$3
    RET_VAL=${VAR:$OFFSET:$LENGTH}
}

# $1 filename

# Change to PF Gazetteer directory
cd $CARRIER_PF_UPDATES_DIR

LOG=log.txt
DownloadedFile=$1
OldFile=
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
RET=0

if [ "${2+1}" == "1" ]
then
    echo "Date: " $DATE > $LOG
    echo "filename: " $DownloadedFile >> $LOG
fi

substring ${DownloadedFile} -3 3
extension=$RET_VAL
old_ext=$((${extension}+1))
substring ${DownloadedFile} 0 9
echo $RET_VAL
oldFile="${RET_VAL}${old_ext}"
#oldFile=`printf  "%02d" ${RET_VAL}`
#printf -v oldFile %02d "$RET_VAL"
#printf -v oldFile %02d "$((10#$RET_VAL - 1))"
extension=${1##*.}
printf -v decr "%s.%0${#extension}d" "${1%.*}" "$((10#$extension - 1))" \
&& cat -- "$decr" "$1" > temp \
&& rm -- "$decr" \
&& mv -- temp "$1"
oldFile="${oldFile}${old_ext}"
echo $oldFile

# move any temporary files if they exist
mv "${DownloadedFile}~" ${DownloadedFile}

# check to see if we got a file
result=$(grep 226 run.ilog)


if [ "${2+1}" == "1" ]
then
    echo "grep found: " $result >> $LOG
fi

if [ -e "${DownloadedFile}" ]
then
   #add back onto filename
   #store back onto var = $OldFile
   #Check if OldFile exist
   #Cat files together and - Cat oldFile DownloadedFile > tempFile
echo ""
fi

if [ "$result" == "" ]
then
     # File not found
     RET=100
else
     RET=10
     # START F4202
     sorted=$(sort -t'+' -k7 ${fileName} > ${fileName}.sorted)
     if [ -e "${fileName}.sorted" ]
     then
        mv "${fileName}" "unsorted/${fileName}.unsorted"
        mv "${fileName}.sorted" ${fileName}
     fi
     # END F4202
fi

if [ "${2+1}" == "1" ]
then
    echo "script ret: " $RET >> $LOG
fi

exit $RET
```

However when I run this I receive the following in the terminal when I type FileName.005 [Pastie](http://pastie.org/3842757)

Whats is supposed to happen is that 
1) I type in a Filename i.e. Filename.005 it checks if it exists

2) Get the old File which is the decremented one from that which would be Filename.004

3) Then cat the contents together to make it one file.

Have I done this correctly. Do excuse me for any mistakes as I am new with bash.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `${DownloadedFile}~` doesn't exist so the move fails. You should first check that it exists before moving.

```
[ -e "${DownloadedFile}~" ] && mv "${DownloadedFile}~" "${DownloadedFile}"
```

Comment: Right, okay so if it checks that the move exists it should clear some of these errors?

Comment: That did work, however I am still left with the remaining: `cat: FileName.004: No such file or directory
cat: FileName.005: No such file or directory
`

Comment: do FileName.005 and FileName.004 exist?

Comment: Well when I run the bash file I type in FilenName.005 and received the following: [link](http://pastie.org/3842867)

Comment: the error shows that FileName.005 and FileName.004 do not exist. Should they?